# Detecting bundles with more than 3 tags

Tags: ros, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to detect a ar_track_alvar bundle with five tags but it only detects the first three tagfrom the xml.

Is it possible to detect bundles with more than three tags?

My xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!-- radius: 4,2 cm -->
<multimarker markers="3">
<marker index="1" status="1">
    <corner x="-1.5" y="-1.5" z="0" />
    <corner x="1.5" y="-1.5" z="0" />
    <corner x="1.5" y="1.5" z="0" />
    <corner x="-1.5" y="1.5" z="0" />
</marker>
<marker index="10" status="1">
    <corner x="-1.5" y="-1.5" z="4.24" />
    <corner x="1.5" y="-1.5" z="4.24" />
    <corner x="1.5" y="1.5" z="4.24" />
    <corner x="-1.5" y="1.5" z="4.24" />
</marker>
<marker index="9" status="1">
    <corner x="-3.8" y="-1.5" z="2.04" />
    <corner x="-2" y="-1.5" z="4.21" />
    <corner x="-2" y="1.5" z="4.21" />
    <corner x="-3.8" y="1.5" z="2.04" />
</marker>
<marker index="11" status="1">
    <corner x="1.8" y="-1.5" z="2.2" />
    <corner x="3.9" y="-1.5" z="4.23" />
    <corner x="3.9" y="1.5" z="4.23" />
    <corner x="1.8" y="1.5" z="2.2" />
</marker>
<marker index="12" status="1">
    <corner x="4" y="-1.5" z="1.44" />
    <corner x="3.9" y="-1.5" z="-1.56" />
    <corner x="3.9" y="1.5" z="-1.56" />
    <corner x="4" y="1.5" z="1.44" />
</marker>
</multimarker>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92621/detecting-bundles-with-more-than-3-tags/) by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2949 on 2013-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wild guess: `<multimarker markers="3">` should probably be replaced by `<multimarker markers="5">`

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-20**:
Your absolutely right! I just saw it by myself. I just deleted this question, then I saw your answer. Will leave it undeleted, so that you get your karma.